# Is there a native object-id or pointer-value in R for R objects?

Tags: r

When I'm debugging code in R I'd like to be able to quickly check if what my variable is pointing to is a different object than I thought (or the same object).

In other languages I can inspect the "pointer-value" or "object-id" -- is there something similar in R?

For example

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
fname <- c("Joe", "John", "Jane")
lname <- c("Brown", "Black", "Boss")
df <- data.frame(id, fname, lname) 
df2 <- df[-2,]
```

Now df and df2 are separate objects.

Is there a quick way that I can check that "identity" that does not involve:

1. tracing the code that produced them
2. value inspection
3. pairwise comparison of the two objects

Comment: Unless you're working with packages that explicitly fiddle with R's internals like data.table, you should never have to worry about this stuff

Comment: That's the beauty of working in a functional language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`address`, `inspect` and `object_size` in the pryr package can be useful here.

```
library(pryr)

address(df)
## [1] "0x7e0b688"

inspect(df)
## <VECSXP 0x7e0b688>
##   <REALSXP 0x7e0d028>
##   <INTSXP 0x96e7278>
## ...snip...
```

For example, the space taken up by `L1` plus the space taken up by `L2` is greater than the space taken up by both of them so clearly there is some sharing going on.  If we inspect them we see that the components of `L2` are still stored in `L1`.

```
L1 <- list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
L2 <- L1[-2]

object_size(L1)
## 248 B
object_size(L2)
## 176 B
object_size(L1, L2)
## 312 B

inspect(L1)
## <VECSXP 0x88622a8>
##   <INTSXP 0x90ba950>
##   <INTSXP 0x90ba870>
##   <INTSXP 0x90ba790>

inspect(L2)
## <VECSXP 0x971dbf8>
##   <INTSXP 0x90ba950>
##   <INTSXP 0x90ba790>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.Internal(inspect(x))` to see information about what is in `x`.  It includes the actual pointer to `x` among a lot of other things.  For example, after your sample code, I see

```
> .Internal(inspect(df))
@7fa48059fe68 19 VECSXP g0c3 [OBJ,NAM(3),ATT] (len=3, tl=0)
  @7fa483d1ba58 14 REALSXP g0c3 [NAM(3)] (len=3, tl=0) 1,2,3
  @7fa4805a0ea8 16 STRSXP g0c3 [NAM(3)] (len=3, tl=0)
    @7fa4829d5898 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "Joe"
    @7fa4829d5828 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "John"
    @7fa4829d57b8 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x60,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "Jane"
  @7fa4805a0e08 16 STRSXP g0c3 [NAM(3)] (len=3, tl=0)
    @7fa4829d5588 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "Brown"
    @7fa4829d5518 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "Black"
    @7fa4829d54a8 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x60] [ASCII] [cached] "Boss"
ATTRIB:
  @7fa4869050d0 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [] 
    TAG: @7fa47b0c2700 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(3),LCK,gp=0x4000] "names" (has value)
    @7fa48059fd78 16 STRSXP g0c3 [NAM(3)] (len=3, tl=0)
      @7fa47e05d668 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "id"
      @7fa47e3d08a0 09 CHARSXP g1c1 [MARK,gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "fname"
      @7fa4829d55f8 09 CHARSXP g0c1 [gp=0x61] [ASCII] [cached] "lname"
    TAG: @7fa47b0c2bd0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(3),LCK,gp=0x4000] "class" (has value)
    @7fa47bc3e440 16 STRSXP g1c1 [MARK,NAM(3)] (len=1, tl=0)
      @7fa47b1b6308 09 CHARSXP g1c2 [MARK,gp=0x61,ATT] [ASCII] [cached] "data.frame"
    TAG: @7fa47b0c24d0 01 SYMSXP g1c0 [MARK,NAM(3),LCK,gp=0x4000] "row.names" (has value)
    @7fa483ba7f78 13 INTSXP g0c1 [NAM(3)] (len=2, tl=0) -2147483648,-3
```

so the pointer to `df` is `@7fa48059fe68`.  If you only want the pointer, you can extract it:

```
getPointer <- function(x) { 
  lines <- capture.output(.Internal(inspect(x)))
  sub(" .*", "", lines[1])
}
```

and then

```
> getPointer(df)
[1] "@7fa48059fe68"
```

Be aware that the `getPointer` function might modify its argument, since it looks at things that you're not supposed to see.